# How can I encrypt data so that a web application can read it, but someone with access to the web server cannot?

Tags: php, security, encryption

I am building a system to store survey data where one of the requirements is that if a hacker gets access to the web server, they are not able to view any of the data. But, the web application does need to be able to decrypt the data and display it (for instance an authenticated user might need to see a table containing survey responses in plain text).

I am having trouble figuring out how the web server could decrypt data without a hacker also being able to do it. Obviously if the decryption key is stored on the server access to the server also entails access to the decryption key.

The only thing I can think of so far is to distribute a decryption key to the users, have them enter it as part of the authentication process, store it in a cookie, and then submit the key with every web request so that it's never stored on the server and instead only in memory for limited periods of time. Obviously this would be served over HTTPS so that the key is also encrypted at transmission time.

I have never seen a system that requires a private key as part of the authentication process, so I'm assuming there is a much better way to do this.

While this is more of a theoretical question, the application will be written in PHP, likely using the Laravel framework, hosted on an Ubuntu server.

Comment: unrealistic goals, if hacker has server access its game over.

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue which can be answered in a few paragraphs. I would suggest you find a development forum (perhaps [Quora](http://www.quora.com/Computer-Programming)?) to work out generalities. Then, when/if you have specific coding issues, come back to Stack Overflow and we'll be glad to help.

Comment: One obvious flaw in your distributed key idea, is that the hacker can still copy the encrypted data, and modify the webserver to leak the key pieces. Then it's a race between you discovering the hacker, and her collecting the entire key.

Comment: Thank you @jh1711. I did think of that. If they get write access to files they could obviously modify code to send them the key. I just couldn't think of anything that didn't have a similar flaw. I am looking into TheGreatContini's very useful suggestions for how the problem has been approached by others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to solve a very hard problem, but here are some pointers if you dare go this direction:

- MIT's [Mylar](https://people.csail.mit.edu/nickolai/papers/popa-mylar-2016-08-29.pdf) was a recent breakthrough trying to provide a practical solution to this problem (in contrast to impractical [homomorphic encryption](https://www.wired.com/2014/11/hacker-lexicon-homomorphic-encryption/)), but it seems to have some [security flaws](https://eprint.iacr.org/2016/920.pdf).  Nevertheless, it is the right direction to be looking for a practical solution.
- There is a concept known as a [zero knowledge web application](https://clipperz.is/blog/2007/08/24/anatomy_zero_knowledge_web_application/), sometimes called "no knowledge", which keeps cryptographic keys on the client side and performs all encryption/decryption on the client side.  Without endorsing a product, it is informative to look at [SpiderOak](https://spideroak.com/features/private-by-design) as an example.  However, be wary that if you are doing the encryption in JavaScript, then a hacker who gets access to your server can replace your JavaScript with their malicious JavaScript.  How to deal with this?  Look at Mylar.

**EDIT**:

The problem with your requirements is that a single bad (or negligent) user can break everything (i.e. expose the decrypted data to anybody and everybody).  However, if that's something you are willing to live with, there are potential solutions, but they are not easy to implement.

One requirement is that cryptographic computations need to happen on client side, and the key that encrypts data needs to be shared securely between users without exposing it to the web application itself.  The most realistic solution to this is having native (thick) clients and [avoiding JavaScript cryptography](https://www.nccgroup.trust/us/about-us/newsroom-and-events/blog/2011/august/javascript-cryptography-considered-harmful/).  However, Mylar claims to solve the JavaScript crypto problem.

You will need public key cryptography to have a chance.  Users will need to be able to exchange the encryption key with each other, and users need to be able to authenticate other users to prevent a MITM scenario happening from a hacked server.

Generally, I'd say you really have your work cut out for you if you want to attempt to solve this, and you will likely run into many problems.  However, the main reason why I am replying is to indicate that in theory, it is not impossible, as shown by recent research in cryptography and web application security.

Comment: Thanks very much. This answer is much more helpful than I imagined was possible. I am still reading the initial whitepaper you linked and investigating  what people have done in this field. I think all of the drawbacks are acceptable. Encrypting the data at all is overkill in my opinion but I don't make the requirements.